# How can i auto resize the column according to content

Tags: tables

I use this code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Offsets 2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{|c}}
\hline\hline
\rowcolor{orange}
student status  &  location type  & outside region & approved outside area (ha) & delivery agent\\ \hline \hline
Current         &  Restoration    & Northwest john Province & 476.0 & 
If the position ... \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
```

But the table is going outside the page. Is there any way that page don't go outside the page and shrink accoring to content and fit on page.

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE? A more readable indentation would be a huge help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example you can chenge

```
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{|c}}
```

onto

```
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{|p{2cm}}}
```

Of, course `2cm` is only an example of width. This gives a paragraph, so entries are never (well, rarely) too long.

Comment: that was perfect , i got that. Is there any way to put the caption on the top of table and remove `table 5` text from there

Comment: @user17 But the caption is over (on the top of) the table. Do you mean the same table, as in your question?